# Add methods to classes without breaking implementations

Tags: java, design-patterns, design-principles

Let say I have 2 classes called `class Cow` ad `class Pig`.

They both implements `interface Animal`.

For the `interface` there are only 2 methods called `public void eat()` and `public void speak()`.

All is fine. But while this seems good making use of `interface`s, I thought that if I ever needed to add method(s) to this `interface`, implementation would break, namely I would need to go implement the new methods in these classes, which breaks the "close-open principle".

So I thought of, in addition to `interface`, I would make use of `abstract` class as well, should it be needed that I needed to add new method(s) in the future.

So, for example, `public class Cow extends ...  implements Animal`.

It sounds like a good plan (if it is not, please correct me).

But the problem is, what if these classes `extend` already some other class? In such case, I could not extend 2 classes.

***So my question is:***

> Is there a pattern where I could declare a common `interface` of
>   related classes while withholding the ability to add new methods in
>   the future that doesn't break the "closed-open principle" and doesn't
>   break implementations?

Comment: This is the problem that Java 8's [*default methods*](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/IandI/defaultmethods.html) attempt to address.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With Java 8 there are [default methods](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/IandI/defaultmethods.html)

```
public interface Animal {

    void eat();
    void speak();
    default void sleep(){}

}
```

Now your `Animal` must override `eat` and `speak` but may choose to override `sleep`.

Pre Java 8 using a `abstract class` was the usual way to protect against having to implement every `interface` method. As you noted, this doesn't work with multiple inheritance so cannot be used to solve all cases.

P.S. don't declare `interface` methods `public`, this is the default visibility for all `interface` members.

Comment: Thank for response. So, back then when a API designer needed to add new method in next release, how would he go about doing it (if the class already extended another class)? Could you please cite me a sample for this (pre-Java 8)? Thanks.

Comment: @Unheilig for an example, see the class [`Number`](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/6-b14/java/lang/Number.java), with `intValue` and `longValue` declared as abstract methods, while `byteValue` and `shortValue`, added since Java 1.1, are provided as concrete implementations.

Comment: @GOTO0 Thanks. But in this case, `Number` is declared as an `abstract` class instead of an `interface` and by concrete implementation you mean the author declare `abstract concrete` methods in the `abstract` class? That is understandable, but in case where it (`Number`) were an `interface` and let assume the subclass already `extend` another class, this wouldn't work, right?

Comment: @Unheilig no, that wouldn't work. The recommendation in this case is to create a new interface extending the old one with new declarations, which would only become available to newer code.

Comment: @Unheilig I can't find I reference for my claim above, but here's an official tutorial explaining the idea: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/IandI/nogrow.html

Comment: @GOTO0 Thanks, interesting. Sounds noob, but I didn't know an `interface` can `extend` another `interface` like this.

Answer (score 1):

In Java 8, interfaces can define [default methods](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/IandI/defaultmethods.html) for this purpose.